# Sealing abstract class or interface in .NET class

Tags: c#, .net

In Scala, it is possible to have define a base class or trait(interface) sealed, so that the only classes which are allowed to extend that class must be placed in the same class.

This is a useful pattern when coding libraries, is there any equivalent in .NET?

Comment: I don't see the advantage, can you please ELI5? (I know what you want, but I don't know why)

Comment: Well with this pattern you can actually implement "sophisticated" enumerations and this is really useful. You can guarantee that there are only a certain number of implementations for your abstract class

Comment: .NET favors the "lives in the same assembly" approach.  With the implicit assumption that whoever knows how to get their code into your assembly is well known to you and but a few cubicles away from yours.  There's no equivalent for *internal* accessibility in the JVM.

Comment: @jnovacho The concept is know as (or at least very related to) a [“discriminated union”](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union), tagged union or sum type. It’s very common in “functional-style” APIs.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The only way to simulate that is to have a private constructor in the abstract class and provide implementation as nested classes.

Example

```
public abstract class Foo
{
  private Foo(int k) {}

  public class Bar : Foo
  {
     public Bar() : base(10) {}
  }
}
```

Comment: +1. Or marking constructor of an abstract class `internal` is another similar option you can get for classes.